# Detect if `\item` is followed by `\begin{enumerate}`

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label = \bfseries \Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\alph*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Is there a way to make `\item` detects it is followed by another `enumerate` environment so that it does not print its label? I could then get something like:

```
[3rd level indent]A.1.a
[3rd level indent]A.1.b
```

I'd like the solution being compatible with `enumitem`.

Comment: that seems like a package bug really, the list code in the format always checks if there is a pending label, which means effectively the previous thing was `\item`. It should not be necessary for `\item` to look ahead.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Same result if I change labels directly with LaTeX, without `enumitem` (as I expected, because `\makelabel` is based on `\llap`).

Comment: That looks like an XY problem. What do yo want to get exactly?

Comment: @JavierBezos See code below screenshot (and thanks for your interest in my question).

Comment: @JavierBezos but doing it by hand you'd increase the label width to match the wider format. the default `\makelabel` only uses `llap` as it "knows" space has been left for the label...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, and same for `enumitem`. Its behavior is similar.

Comment: @cjorssen And what should happen with `\begin{enumerate} \item X \item \begin{enumerate}`?

Comment: @JavierBezos `[1st level indent]A. [newline] [2nd level indent]B.1`. Or maybe `[1st level indent]A. [newline] [1st level indent]B.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\remlabels{\if@inlabel\setbox\@labels=\hbox{}\fi}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate,1]{before = \remlabels, label = \Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{before = \remlabels, label = \Alph{enumi}.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{before = \remlabels, label = \Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\alph*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
% \item 2nd
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item 3r
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). This is a good complement to David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the `\item` macro to look ahead for `\begin{enumerate}`. The following code isn't pretty but does that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label = \bfseries \Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\alph*.}

\makeatletter
\let\@lditem=\item
\def\n@witem\begin#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{enumerate}}{%
    % Use empty label but step the counter
    \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\@lditem[]\begin{#1}%
  }{%
    \@lditem\begin{#1}%
  }%
}
\def\item{%
  \@ifnextchar\begin{%
    % Then check for {enumerate}
    \n@witem
  }{%
    \@lditem
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item[ZZ]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{equation}
    1+1=2
    \end{equation}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great (+1). Works fine. Tranks.

Comment: Unfortunately, spacings fail with `\setlist{wide}`.

Comment: As far as I can see, `\setlist{wide}` makes `\item' insert all three labels in a row with gaps between them. So, indeed spacing becomes wrong. I'm not sure I can easily fix this.

Comment: You can use something like `\setlist{wide = -5pt}` as a very ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you mean you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label = \bfseries \Alph*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label = \bfseries \Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\alph*.}


\makeatletter
\def\@trivlist{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \@topsepadd \topsep
  \ifvmode
    \advance\@topsepadd \partopsep
  \else
    \unskip \par
  \fi
  \if@inlabel
    \@noparitemtrue
     \setbox\@labels\hbox{}%
    \@noparlisttrue
  \else
    \if@newlist \@noitemerr \fi
    \@noparlistfalse
    \@topsep \@topsepadd
  \fi
  \advance\@topsep \parskip
  \leftskip \z@skip
  \rightskip \@rightskip
  \parfillskip \@flushglue
  \par@deathcycles \z@
  \@setpar{\if@newlist
             \advance\par@deathcycles \@ne
             \ifnum \par@deathcycles >\@m
               \@noitemerr
               {\@@par}%
             \fi
           \else
             {\@@par}%
           \fi}%
  \global \@newlisttrue
  \@outerparskip \parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\item hmmm
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I think I can wrap your code inside the `before` key of enumitem keyvals. Now, I'd like to understand `:-)` Can you comment a bit your code? Thanks (+1, obviously).

Comment: @cjorssen you may prefer to use etoolbox to patch all I added was a single line `\setbox\@labels\hbox{}%` that discards any pending label from outside the list at the point that trivlist is anyway doing `\if@inlabel` which is testing for exactly this situation.

Comment: This is the way to go. The point is `\item` prints nothing, but waits until there is text. Therefore, a `\begin{enumerate}` just after `\item` can modify its label (and this is the very reason I said it was an XY problem). I'm not sure `before` can be used for that - I must investigate, but in the meanwhile you can use `etoolbox` as suggested by David.